# Unable to make drop down option box read only

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make my a dropdown box read-only and no matter what I do, I can't seem to make it read-only.

Non working code.

```
<?php 
if($_SESSION['id'] == $all_information['complain_from']){ ?>
    <select name="complain_form" class="custom-select">
        <option value="<?php echo $all_information['complain_from']; ?>" readonly><?php echo $_SESSION['real_name']; ?></option>
    </select>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <select name="complain_form" class="custom-select">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a name</option>
<?php
foreach($all_account_info as $account_info){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $account_info['id']; ?>" <?php if($all_information['complain_from'] == $account_info['id']){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> readonly>
<?php 
    echo $account_info['real_name']; 
?>
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: What do you expect the option of a select box to behave when you "click" it --- if it is "read-only"??

Comment: This selectable option is on another page. This is a page that the results can't be edited on.

Comment: `if($_SESSION['id'] == $all_information['complain_from']){ ?>
<dl><dd><?php echo $all_information['complain_from']; ?></dd><dt><?php echo $_SESSION['real_name']; ?></dt></dl>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to show a selected value in a `<select>` element you can set the `disabled` attribute for that `<select>`:

```
<select name="complain_form" class="custom-select" disabled>
<option value="<?php echo $all_information['complain_from']; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['real_name']; ?></option>
</select>
```

This will grey out the `<select>` and nothing will happen when clicking it

Comment: thank you for your help :)